# Change the minimum OS requirments of my iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, build, requirements, target, operating-system

I made a simple application, then submitted for review.
After that the app details claims that the minimum OS requirmentes is 3.1.2 (I work with that SDK).

**If I change my Target's iPhone OS Deployment Target to a lower iPhone OS, then could it be "fix" my problem? Is there any risk of it?** I Use some UI(Image)Views, page-flip animations, NSTimer, UIDevice for battery info, and AudioToolbox framework to have some system sound  thats all.

How can I test my app on a 2.0 simulator? Where can I find it to install? Do I need to install a whole 2.0 SDK? Where can I find it? I've googled for it, but still cant find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to downgrade it.  For instance, I have an app that was originally 3.0, but I've since decreased requirements to 2.0.

To do this:

1. Double-click on your Target's name in Xcode to bring up the Target Info.
2. Go to the Build tab and search for "iPhone OS Deployment Target".
3. Pick whichever SDK you want to use as your minimum requirements.

One thing is that it won't tell you if it doesn't work on a certain version.  You'll have to compare your methods with which ones are available in each version manually.

You can help curb this by changing your Base SDK too:

1. Same place, search for "Base SDK".
2. Change it to the lowest iPhone OS Device SDK you can/want.  On Snow Leopard, this is 2.2.1; Leopard can go as low as 2.0 if you installed it with Xcode.

Good luck! :)

Comment: You serious?
Look up for every classes I used so far in the application, and read documentations to compare? I can hardly belive that I cannot test it on an iPhone 2.0 simulator.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. I'm just lucky I still have an old iPhone running 2.2. ;)

Comment: Ok. I think I'm gonna do this (Simply changed the SDK after change deployment target, and the app seems running).

So should I reject my binary from the appStore with the newly compiled build?

Comment: Or maybe they will test it for compatibility?

Comment: No, they only test it on 3.0.  BTW, try changing the Base SDK too. That at least verifies that you're using methods on 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, apple states somewhere that when using new SDK's i think you build for the latest software update.

Comment: Maybe this is for encourage the iPhone users to update their device?

Comment: Can you link something, where apple claims that?

Comment: it justs needs to be 3.0 tested and compatible, it doesn't need to be built for 3.0.

Comment: You say that a 3.0 user will be able to download it, even if it's details claims it has the minimum requirments 3.1.2?